# No callback from iOS LinkedIn SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, callback, linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn SDK and am trying to authenticate with LinkedIn, but I don't get a callback from LinkedIn to my app. I'm using the following code

```
 [LISDKSessionManager createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, LISDK_EMAILADDRESS_PERMISSION, nil]
                                      state:nil // @"some state"
                     showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES
                               successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {}
                                 errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {}];
```

I am using the correct `appId` in the Info.plist and all my bundles are added to the LinkedIn dev center. I've also tried to use different versions of the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

This might be trivial, but in your question you're not actually doing anything in your callback blocks, you're just passing in an empty block.

In the success block, check the `[[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session]` for a valid user session.  In the error block, check the error object's description and alert the user if necessary:

```
[LISDKSessionManager 
createSessionWithAuth:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:LISDK_BASIC_PROFILE_PERMISSION, nil]
    state:nil
    showGoToAppStoreDialog:YES
    successBlock:^(NSString *returnState) {
        NSLog(@"Success!");
        LISDKSession *session = [[LISDKSessionManager sharedInstance] session];
    }
    errorBlock:^(LISDKAuthError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
];
```

More potential reasons this could happen:

You're app isn't set up for App Transport Security properly.  Set `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to true in the NSAppTransportSecurity settings in your Info.plist or whitelist the LinkedIn URLs:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>linkedin.com</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>                
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Also make sure you whitelist LinkedIn's URL schemes:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>linkedin</string>
    <string>linkedin-sdk2</string>
    <string>linkedin-sdk</string>
</array>
```